# How to find duplicate files in android

Tags: android, file, duplicates

I am finding  duplicate files by using library Commons IO 2.5 API [Here is a link](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-io/commons-io/2.4). And i am using this tutorial [this](http://www.simplecodestuffs.com/compare-two-files-by-content-in-java/) . But problem is that this procedure take a long time to compare.The code is below

```
 public static PhotoItem compare(File f,List<File> fil) throws IOException {
    PhotoItem photoItem = new PhotoItem();
    File fisss = null;
    int count = 1;
    for(int i=0;i<fil.size();i++) {
        if (FileUtils.contentEquals(f, fil.get(i))) {
            fisss = fil.get(i);
            count++;
            fil.remove(i);
            photoItem.setFilePath(fisss.getAbsolutePath());
        }
    }
    photoItem.setId(String.valueOf(count));
    return photoItem;
}
```

Please help me this take really a long time to compare more then 300 files. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

make a background service which load and compare images in background and save data in whether database or share prefrence and show it to user when he open app you just have to check when user add new file or delete some file

Comment: But if user want to remove some files in user_interface how i handle this situation.... Now service is also take a long time to compare it again :(

Comment: now when user click on the delete button then populate the adapter with 1 minus number of items

Comment: simply 1 lower(minus) the counter of items

Comment: one more logic you have to implement that if. the counter is 1 then you not have to show it in the adapter

Comment: i think it will help you best

Answer (score 0):

You may be able to precompute some kind of hash values and metadata (file size at least) for your file list in advance and then search vs those precomputed values.